# Minecraft Java 1.19.4: How to get the items in multiple hopper minecarts to end up in one double chest?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I am trying to make a storage system for my cocoa beans for cases I drop when harvesting so I don't necessarily have to go towards them to pick them up if they don't automatically go into my inventory. Here is what the setup of the logs and beans looks like:

[image: cocoa beans and logs placement]

For flat drawing (I don't know if this is any better):
[image: Flat drawing displaying cocoa beans and logs placement]

I already have the idea in mind of having a hopper minecart per stack of logs going around in a circle so it can easily pick up the beans through the block above which is at the y level I will be standing on. However, I'm not sure how to get the beans that go into each one of the hopper minecarts into one double chest. I'd like for it to be with the least number of hoppers possible, meaning there would not be a hopper on every block under the hopper minecart rail, but also with very little redstone as well since this is in a Purpur server. So the question is, how can I get the beans that are in the hopper minecarts into one double chest?

Comment: either 2 hoppers or very complicated rail circuit

Comment: what's stopping you from just feeding them into the same chest?